# What can feltrite be used for?

Tags: rage-2

I know Feltrite is used to upgrade your weapons and skills. However, with the ease that it can be acquired with it is not difficult to fully upgrade those skill trees and still have thousands of Feltrite Crystals left over.

Other than personal upgrades, can Feltrite Crystals be traded or consumed for any other purpose? They're used for healing, but as far as I can tell there isn't any use for the currency once you've upgraded your character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feltrite can be used for 3 things, all of which you've already identified:

- **Upgrading skills**
- **Upgrading weapons**
- **Healing yourself**

Do note that there are two DLC packs coming out later in 2019, which will add more weapons and abilities to the game, and thus more things to spend feltrite on.

Sources:

- [What is feltrite for in Rage 2?](https://guides.gamepressure.com/rage-2/guide.asp?ID=50097)
- [Rage 2 guide: Currencies, upgrades, and components](https://www.polygon.com/rage-2-guide/2019/5/17/18629218/currencies-upgrades-components-cash-feltrite-perks-mods-projects-weapon-vehicle-core-augmentations)
- [Rage 2 Tips: 16 Things the Game Doesn’t Tell You](https://www.fanbyte.com/guides/rage-2-tips/)
- [2019 Rage 2 Roadmap](https://twitter.com/rage/status/1126923186111766529)